# S1 Bing Web Search API daily user search limit? Paid subscription

Tags: bing-api

I have upgraded to an umlimited pay as you go subscription with our S1 tier. We are having issues when trying to test with users getting the : You've exceeded the daily search limit, try again tomorrow.

What is this?

Its not mentioned ANYWHERE about api limits per IP address?

Any assistance is much appreciated. I see other search platforms using bing api and don't seem to have the same restriction..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a support question for an off-site vendor or service and not a programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines.

Comment: What is the error code you are getting? Can you confirm you are using S1 and not F0? There are limits on transactions per second but nothing at daily level as mentioned in the pricing plan.